# pm2 reload for a nuxt app is not picking up code changes without deleting and restarting

Tags: nuxt.js, github-actions, devops, pm2, cicd

I have a github workflow that deploys and restarts a Nuxt app using pm2. Everything works splendidly aside from code changes not being reflecting. Here is the dev workflow:

```
# This workflow will do a clean installation of node dependencies, cache/restore them, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-nodejs

name: Development

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "develop" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [dev]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Copy .env file to build directory
      run: cp /var/www/dev.code.com/env_config/.env.dev.code.com /var/www/actions-runner/_work/code/code/.env

    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version-file: '.nvmrc'
        cache: 'yarn'

    - name: Clean up generated nuxt files and caches
      run: yarn run clean
    
    - name: Run yarn
      run: |
       yarn install --frozen-lockfile
       yarn build

    - name: Copy output and ecosystem config to DocumentRoot
      run: |
        mkdir -p /var/www/dev.code.com/$(date +%Y%m%d)
        cp -R /var/www/actions-runner/_work/code/code/.output/. /var/www/dev.code.com/$(date +%Y%m%d)
        cp /var/www/actions-runner/_work/code/code/ecosystem.config.js /var/www/dev.code.com/$(date +%Y%m%d)/ecosystem.config.js

        # Create new symlink to directory with date timestamp
        ln -sfn /var/www/dev.code.com/$(date +%Y%m%d) /var/www/dev.code.com/latest
    
    - name: Install pm2 global
      run: |
        npm install pm2@latest -g
        pm2 -V
        pm2 list
    
    - name: Restart PM2 processes
      run: |
        cd /var/www/dev.code.com/latest
        PM2_HOME=/etc/pm2daemon pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js -i max
```

The `ecosystem.config.js` is this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'App name',
      port: process.env.PORT || '3000',
      script: './server/index.mjs',
    },
  ],
};
```

Pretty basic and straightforward. Only one environment since this is a simple static website. At one point the clustering was configured in the `ecosystem.config.js` file:

```
exec_mode: 'cluster',
instances: 'max',
```

but has since been moved to the CLI command. After the workflow is complete, the only way to get the code changes to be reflected is to stop and/or delete the pm2 processes and restart manually. This could be done in the workflow, but either way it does create a small amount of downtime. Is there a way to improve either the workflow or ecosystem file to reload without downtime? I know `pm2 restart...` and `pm2 startOrRestart` works as well, but once again there is downtime. Is reload just flawed or have I completely missed something. I also tested in `fork_mode` with similar results.

If it's helpful, this workflow deploys to a Linode server and served via apache.